# Multiplexing L298N motor drivers

Tags: motor, multiplexer

I'm working on a project where I need to drive 20 motors with no speed control just running the motors. But I don't have 20 available pins to connect to all the drivers directly. Is it okay to multiplex these drivers with pulling all the GNDs HIGH and all the input pins LOW and then reversing the pins of the needed motor eg. I have to run the row 3 column 4 motor I put the row 3 LOW and column 4 HIGH. Is it a preferred method of doing it or should I choose another method? Sorry for the bad diagram.

[image]

Comment: Please can you add a diagram - but not a photo of a hand sketch, they're far too big. No photos. Draw one in MS Paint or something else. The schematic editor here is very easy to use.

Comment: Added the diagram. Didn't connect them to an Arduino but assume they are.

Comment: Upvote and top marks for adding a proper diagram: neat, small and clear.

Comment: Do you need the motors to be able to reverse, or just rotate in one direction? At the moment for every motor you select, many other motors will also be partially activated.

Comment: Just one direction is needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay to multiplex these drivers with pulling all the GNDs HIGH

No! According to the [L298 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/L298_H_Bridge.pdf), input pins must not go more than 0.3 V below ground. Another possible problem is that each motor driver would need its own **fully isolated** power supply to keep the grounds separate.

If the motor drivers had opto-coupled inputs then you could do it, because the optocoupler provides the required isolation and its input is an LED that only lights up with one polarity. Some L298 motor driver boards have optocouplers built in, but they usually connect them all to a common supply rail so you can't multiplex more that one input independently.

You could add external optocouplers like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqv2C2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> Is it a preferred method of doing it or should I choose another
> method?

Using a matrix of optocouplers has the advantage of keeping controller ground noise (caused by high motor current) away from sensitive parts of the circuit such as the MCU.

Another method would be to use 1-of-n decoder ICs to convert binary to single outputs, eg. [74HC4514](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4515.pdf?ts=1617579939495&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD74HC4515) (you need two of them because each IC only has 16 outputs). This would free up several I/O pins because you only need 5 or 6 pins to control two 1 of 16 decoders. On the minus side you would have to be more careful with routing of ground wires to the motor controllers.

Or you could shift registers such as the [74HC595](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scls041i/scls041i.pdf?ts=1617548063007&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) (3 required), or an I/O expander IC.

Comment: Bruce, I know you know this stuff better than I. But wouldn't it be possible to operate the L298N as:$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|ccc}
\text{ROW}&\text{in}_1&\text{in}_2&\text{en}\\
\hline
\text{Active}&L&L&H\\
\text{Inctive}&L&L&L
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|ccc}
\text{COL}&\text{in}_1&\text{in}_2&\text{en}\\
\hline
\text{Active}&H&H&H\\
\text{Inctive}&H&H&L
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

Comment: @jonk when I think about it, with only one motor direction needed you could have eg. 4 enable lines selecting 'rows' and 5 other lines selecting 'columns', doing the same job as the matrix.